# Postfix: Как запретить доступ извне на определенные внутренние групповые рассылки

Tags: postfix

Мне нужно запретить доступ извне (чтобы не смогли получать письма) на определенные внутренние групповые  рассылки all@mydomain.com, но при этом сделать доступ определенным внешним доменам.

К примеру: на all@mydomain.com может отправить user@mail.ru

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = all_class
all_class = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/all-senders, reject

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/all-recipient,
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access,
        reject_rbl_client zombie.dnsbl.sorbs.net,
        reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
        reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
        reject_rbl_client multihop.dsbl.org,
        reject_rbl_client work.rsbs.express.ru,
        reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
        permit
```

В all-senders настроено, кто может отправлять:

```
user1@mydomain.com   OK
user2@mydomain.com   OK
```

в all-recipient ограниченные групповые рассылки:

```
all@mydomain.com permit_mynetworks all_class
```

Для наших пользователей правила работают.

применил эти правила для запрета извне, но не работает.

```
check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access 
all@mydomain.com   permit_mynetworks, reject
```

Что здесь не так делаю?